# SSAS aggregation not being used

Tags: performance, ssas, aggregation

So I have a fairly hefty cube that won't be much good without aggregations. I'm still in dev phases, so I'm manually attempting usage based agg design. I'm aggregating some of the main queries that we've designed. However, every time I pull these up, it looks like it's reading through each partition it hits (biggest groups are partitioned monthly).

I decided I'd try to narrow it down. After all, may just be the queries, or a blip, or what have you. So, using SQL Server Profiler and [BIDS Helper](http://www.codeplex.com/bidshelper), I created one and only one aggregation on one of my measure groups. I then ran said query and looked at the profiler, and it again hit every single partition, and didn't grab a thing out of an aggregation.

My only guess is that this is due to the fact that the measure being pulled back has a measure expression (currency conversion). Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: can you close it then? mark your own response as 'answer'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the [Identifying Bottlenecks](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=975C5BB2-8207-4B4E-BE7C-06AC86E24C13&displaylang=en) whitepaper, measure expressions invalidate aggregations. Once I removed all measure expressions from the measure group, the aggregations were again in use. Hoorah!

Comment: The link is broken, was it something like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/identify-bottlenecks?view=sql-server-2017